# Go - converting ...interface{} to a struct

Tags: go

I have a scenario where I'm calling a function leveraging a common background worker thread that has arguments as `func somefunction(data ...interface{})` to be generic and reusable across the application.

In one of the functions, the number of arguments are more and in the unction definition, I am casting the array items individually like

```
someVar := data[0].(string)
```

Now this approach is fine when I'm usually dealing with 1-2 arguments. But it becomes tedious when the number of arguments increases.

So is there a cleaner way to parse the elements into a struct in the order of their appearance?

My objective is to do this in a cleaner way rather than individually getting one from array and casting to a string variable.

Sample code explaining the scenario https://go.dev/play/p/OScAjyyLW0W

Comment: You could write a helper function that uses reflection, but it'll be slower than using type assertions and assigning manually. On the other hand, this is a weak abstraction. If you want to construct a struct value for the arguments, you should be passing a struct value in the first place.

Comment: @icza Thanks, this helped. I had to modify things a bit for which I was skeptical. But it turned out to be the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package to set fields on a value from a slice of interface{}. The fields must be [exported](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

```
// setFields set the fields in the struct pointed to by dest
// to args. The fields must be exported.
func setFields(dest interface{}, args ...interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(dest).Elem()
    for i, arg := range args {
        v.Field(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(arg))
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
type PersonInfo struct {  
    ID       string  // <-- note exported field names.
    Name     string
    Location string
}

var pi PersonInfo
setFields(&pi, "A001", "John Doe", "Tomorrowland")
```

[Playground Example](https://go.dev/play/p/hLudeBBvVpG).